# VCXO - different voltage tuning mechanism

Tags: vco

I am trying to design a VCXO PCB using [CVCO55CC-2328-2536](https://www.crystek.com/microwave/admin/webapps/welcome/files/vco/CVCO55CC-2328-2536.pdf).

In the datasheet it is mentioned that the tuning voltage for this particular VCXO lies between
0.5(Min) - 4.5(Max). As the output frequency of this VCXO is completely dependent on the Tuning voltage, this voltage needs to accurate.

I know voltage divider comes in to every ones mind but what options other than than the voltage divider?

Which kind of circuits/mechanisms can be followed for getting the tuning voltage for various frequency options?

Comment: *this voltage needs to accurate.* But even if you did apply an accurate voltage, will you then get an accurate output frequency? I do not think you will. If you need a stable and predictable output frequency then my guess would be to use a PLL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop#:~:text=A%20phase%2Dlocked%20loop%20or,detector%20in%20a%20feedback%20loop. in which this VCXO is used as the oscillator and you use another (fixed frequency) oscillator as the **reference frequency**.

Comment: normally, this question just doesn't arise, because of the way you're using the VCO in a closed loop application. How are you planning to use the VCO?

Comment: How many ways can you think of, for generating a stable voltage?

Comment: I am not sure that part is even a crystal oscillator. But you not only need an accurate voltage, you need a very stable, low noise voltage because any noise on the tuning input will translate to phase noise

Comment: @JorenVaes I agree that this isn't a crystal oscillator. I think it is an oscillator based on a **tunable** resonator similar to what is described here: https://www.everythingrf.com/community/what-is-a-dro-dielectric-resonator-oscillator So compared to a crystal, you get a "dirtier" signal (higher phase noise) but in return you get **frequency tunability**.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That is what I want to know! I thought of using low noise adjustable voltage regulators?

Comment: As @Bimpelrekkie says, the linked device is not a VCXO in the first place, otherwise it would only be tunable over about +/-100ppm (I managed +/-150ppm on one design).

Comment: Your oscillator spec doesn't mention how frequency drifts with temperature. Your voltage source may have to have temperature-compensating components added if you expect a stable output frequency.

Comment: *I thought of using low noise adjustable voltage regulators?* You're only focusing on the DC voltage but as I mentioned, even an ultra-stable-noise-free DC voltage will **not** give you a stable frequency at the output. The oscillator circuit in the VCXO **will** introduce **phase noise** and the **temperature** (and aging) will introduce **frequency drift**. Those might not be an issue for your application but **only** focusing on that DC voltage is **bad engineering** as it is not the complete story.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* generate a PWM signal digitally,then filter it and apply it to the tuning input.

Of course, this would be a monumentally bad idea, since the PWM frequency components which were not filtered out would modulate the oscillator output. Without knowing what your signal bandwidth is, there is no way to tell if this would be a problem - but it's hard to think of an application which would do well by this approach.* Or, you could make a very, very good filter - but if you're at the stage of "the obvious way to vary voltage is with voltage dividers" this is probably not a reasonable requirement.

But you *could* do it.

*For instance, you might be using your oscillator to produce a fairly low-resolution analog telemetry channel using a 2.3 to 2.5 GHz span to transmit -.5 to 4.5 volts. A possible example would be a single-channel data link for a model rocket. Since the voltage in/frequency out curve is not very linear, you wouldn't get much accuracy.

But you *could* do it.